# Convert Chinese Character and UTF-8

Tags: java, xml, spring

i having issue to get the value from data is a Chinese character when i get from the resultSet the chinese character was become  µ¥?ÚûÇ. My resultset is a xml that stored in database. i would like to convert back the µ¥?ÚûÇ to Chinese character.
the original chinese character is "澳門" but when i extract from my database it wash showing µ¥?ÚûÇ.  When i see my xml in my Sybase database in Interactive SQL by using Charset UTF-8 it was able to see my chinese character 澳門.

```
  Object[] results = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();
  xml = String.valueOf(results[2]);
```

Comment: You likely have some container that is not using UTF-8 as it’s character encoding. Check how you write that XML to the database. Check the database’s character encoding. You don’t provide enough details for us to diagnose the issue. You should provide enough detail for us to recreate the issue.

Comment: I have checked in the database when I change my encoding in Interactive SQL to UTF-8 I was able to that xml in chinese character. The problem is when I try to select from the table and not able to show the Chinese character.

Comment: You should post your desired Chinese character in the Question, or at least its Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) number.

Comment: i have added the chinese character, i currently out of idea on this UTF encoding, is it regarding the database connection or result set required to do encoding ?